# How can i repeat active class only once?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

My v-for works properly but thing is i want my bootstrap 4 css .active class also repeat.i want to bootstrap 4 active class repeat only once.
please suggest me how can i get rid of this.

```js
var app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
   subjects: ['CSE','EEE','BBA']
  }
 })
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Trykker','Spectral SC', serif;
 }
 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
  font-family: 'Spectral SC', serif;
 }
 p{
  font-family: 'Trykker', serif;
 }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="app">

   
   <ul class="list-group">
       <li v-for="subject in subjects" class="list-group-item active">{{ subject }}</li>
   </ul>

   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for only active the selected subject?
You can check for the [class and style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) on vuejs official website. I have included the example.

```js
var app = new Vue ({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            activeSubject: 'CSE',
            subjects: ['CSE','EEE','BBA']
        }
    })
```

```css
body{
        font-family: 'Trykker','Spectral SC', serif;
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
        font-family: 'Spectral SC', serif;
    }
    p{
        font-family: 'Trykker', serif;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="app">

            
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li v-for="subject in subjects" class="list-group-item" :class="{active:subject==activeSubject}">{{ subject }}</li>
            </ul>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```